# Solving for time with the quadratic Equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm using a quadratic equation to solve for time, plus I already have the answer, but the answer is wrong. I have looked at it for about a day and still never found out why.

```
A = accelerationY/2
B = velocityIY
C = Yinitial
time1 = -B + math.sqrt(B**2-4*A*C)/2*A 
time2 = -B - math.sqrt(B**2-4*A*C)/2*A
```

I'm using python 3 and the math module.

Comment: Your formula is wrong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula.  It took you a whole day?  Shameful.

Comment: Tip: It should be `/(2*A)` instead of `/2*A`. That `A` is being multiplied. You need to read up on operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
time1 = (-B + math.sqrt(B**2-4*A*C)) / (2*A)
```

and similar for `time2`.

The `2 * A` needs to be under the `-B` term too, plus you have a slip in that denominator (you need to divide by `A`, not multiply).

Answer (score 1):

You should again check your formulas, what is the full denominator and numerator of the fraction etc. Then you should put extra parentheses as

```
time1 = ( -B + math.sqrt(B**2-4*A*C) ) / ( 2*A )
time2 = ( -B - math.sqrt(B**2-4*A*C) ) / ( 2*A )
```